# angular animation on ng-click

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using angular and I need to add an animation that will increase the size of the image.

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item images-parent">
  <img src="img/carryout-icon.jpg" class="left-image"></img>
  <img src="img/or.jpg" class="center-image"></img>
  <img src="img/delivery-icon.jpg" class="right-image"></img>
  </div> 
</div>
```

demo:

http://play.ionic.io/app/933b5926b6da

I want to add same animation/transition to first and third image when the user clicks on it and should be removed when user clicks on the other one i.e if I click on first image, it increases in size, then if I click on the other one, first one goes back to normal and second one has that animation.

Also, I have tried doing it but I am just not able to get ngAnimate, I am not a CSS person either. Also, Any resources to help someone like me would be appreciated.

I see events such as ngView , ng if e.t.c But I do not really want these animations on such events. Only when user clicks on the image. Am I even supposed to use ngAnimate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know which particular image you intend to increase it's size on click, but here's one way to go about it.
You can create a css class that increases the image, and you toggle on or off with [NgClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), A tutorial [Scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

That is to make sure it changes class, but if you want to toggle on/off the class when you click [CodePen](http://codepen.io/hbuchel/pen/xtbzc) `snippet below`

```
$scope.isActive = false;
$scope.activeButton = function() {
 $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
}
```

Comment: I need  to increase the size of left aligned and right aligned images on respective clicks. When left aligned image is clicked, its size should increase and when right aligned image is clicked, left should come back to normal size and right should increase in size.

Comment: I don't see anything relevant in this punkr?Did I miss anything? Could you please check if that's the link you wanted to share?

Comment: Thank you :) That scotch link is great too :) :)